# How to modify JS with mitmproxy?

Tags: javascript, websites, proxy

I am trying to reverse engineer a heavily obfuscated web application, and I would like to modify the JS to add logging. So far, I've set up mitmproxy, but I can't figure out what the best way to edit the JS files is. Ideally this would be done in a way where I can save the edits and have them automatically apply when I refresh the page.

Comment: You can script mitmproxy to modify the body of certain responses: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/simple/send_reply_from_proxy.py I would save the obfuscated JS file, unminimize and add your logging code then save it to a file and modify the Mitm proxy script so that it returns the file content as body.